# Multiplayer Synchronization

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I am developing multiplayer game in unity. For multiplayer i am using photon networking library. I created room and join client successfully.

But Problem is I am doing gameobject movent by this code:

```
public GameObject player;
IEnumerator Moving (String temp)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        player.transform.DOMove (CurrentPositionHolder, 0.5f).SetEase 
           (Ease.Linear);   
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
    }
}
```

DoMoveis library here.

Problem is player movement is not synchronized.

For Synchronization I add photonview component to player gameobject.

And i call coroutine though RPC like this.

```
player.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC ("Moving", PhotonTargets.All, "temp");
```

Accordingly i changed coroutine like this:

```
[PunRPC]
IEnumerator Moving (String temp)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        player.transform.DOMove (CurrentPositionHolder, 0.5f).SetEase 
           (Ease.Linear);   
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
    }
}
```

I got this error

Illegal view ID:0 method: Moving GO:player
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

Comment: Are you instantiating the object using `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate`?

Comment: No, I instantiate it normally, Is it required to instantiate like that?

Comment: As far as I know, it is. Check out the tutorial documentation.

Comment: I instantiate using PhotonNetwork.Instantiate, Error message not showing 
but if gameobject on client side move, it not showing at server side and vice-versa. I want sync it.

Comment: We'd need more details if you want that solved. Try making one of the tutorials work for you first, then apply what you learn to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Problem gets solved. I call Moving enumerator from method not directly using RPC.
And Make method call using RPC.

And Most important thing is use transfrom instead of gameobject like this:

```
transform.DOMove (CurrentPositionHolder, 0.5f).SetEase(Ease.Linear);
```